# Randomize values in structure in R

Tags: r

To those not doing anything better on a Friday night, I have a structure and I need to randomize the values contained in it. First I need to take all the values (here it is 1 through 11), randomize them and add them back in the same breakdown as the original structure. I.e still 4 values in '1' but they are four randomly selected from the 1 to 11 values, same for '2' and finally 3 random values in '3', and all without replacement.

So:

```
strct <- structure(list(`1` = 1:4, `2` = 5:8, `3` = 9:11), .Names =
 c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Yielding for example:

```
structure(list(`1` = c(4, 6, 1, 11), `2` = c(2, 5, 8, 9), `3` = c(3, 7, 10)),
  .Names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
split(sample(unlist(strct, use.names=FALSE)), 
            cumsum(sequence(sapply(strct, length))==1))

#$`1`
#[1] 5 2 1 6

#$`2`
#[1]  3  9 11  8

#$`3`
#[1] 10  7  4
```